# update UI (invoke) native

Tags: tizen, tizen-native-app

How to invoke changes on UI. for example change progress bar like shown on this button click handler:

```
void view1_Button_onclicked(uib_view1_view_context *vc, Evas_Object *obj, void *event_info)
{
    eext_circle_object_value_set(vc->progressbar1, 50.0);
    sleep(2); //or do anything intensive like network load
    eext_circle_object_value_set(vc->progressbar1, 100.0);
}
```

Comment: Can you please clarify elaborately what type of changes you need in UI ? Which version of  Native UI Builder you used between  UI Builder - Navigation and UI Builder - Single View ?

Comment: in example i used to update progessbar value. It also doesn't work for updating label text. At the end of method i only see final result. I am using latest version Native UI builder with single view

Comment: I think you create a circle progressbar. So firstly you need to create a circle progressbar.


You can create the circle progressbar by using the " eext_circle_object_progressbar_add() " function. 


Before using the circle progressbar, set its minimum and maximum values  with the " eext_circle_object_value_min_max_set() " function.

Comment: Everything is created, however when updating it doesn't work until method end. This actually makes sense but i would like to provide some feedback to the user using progress bar while method is executed.

Comment: Can you please share you full source code ?

Comment: Did you solve your problem? If solved please share with us what was the problem with your code. If still problem exists, please share your source code so that we can identify the problem.

Comment: Of course not :(
here is my complete source: https://www.dropbox.com/s/78w89qxmvo7kzq1/tizenWidget.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

EFL UI bascially works on main loop with only one thread.

so EFL system can't draw UI until you finish your some job in your event function.

you can make another thread for your job and start thread in the event function.

but use ecore idle functions for using eext_circle_object_value_set.

most EFL and tizen function must be used in main thread.

so run your job in another thread and request progress value setter to main thread with ecore main loop functions.

---

EFL Ecore supply sync and async function for request job to main loop.
`ecore_main_loop_thread_safe_call_async` and
`ecore_main_loop_thread_safe_call_sync` can be used instead of ecore_idle functions.

so here is simple example with Elementary progresses.
I don't use eext functions in this source but you can refer elm_progressbar_value_set instead of eext.

```
#include <Elementary.h>

struct progresses
{
  Evas_Object *moving;
  Evas_Object *status;
};

struct progress_with_value
{
  Evas_Object *progress;
  double value;
};

static void* progress_setter_async(void *data)
{
  struct progress_with_value *pv = data;
  elm_progressbar_value_set(pv->progress, pv->value);
  return NULL;
}

static void some_job_cb(void *data, Ecore_Thread *thread)
{
  int i=0;
  struct progresses *p = data;

  struct progress_with_value pv_moving = {p->moving, 0.0};
  struct progress_with_value pv_status = {p->status, 0.0};

  ecore_main_loop_thread_safe_call_sync(progress_setter_async, &pv_moving); 
  ecore_main_loop_thread_safe_call_sync(progress_setter_async, &pv_status); 

  while (i++<=10)
  {
    usleep(200000);
    pv_moving.value = i * 0.1;
    ecore_main_loop_thread_safe_call_sync(progress_setter_async, &pv_moving); 
  }

  pv_status.value = 1.0;
  ecore_main_loop_thread_safe_call_sync(progress_setter_async, &pv_status); 
}

static void on_clicked_cb(void *data, Evas_Object *obj, void *event_info)
{
  ecore_thread_run(some_job_cb, NULL, NULL, data);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  Evas_Object *win;

  elm_init(argc, argv);
  elm_policy_set(ELM_POLICY_QUIT, ELM_POLICY_QUIT_LAST_WINDOW_CLOSED);

  win = elm_win_add(NULL, "sample", ELM_WIN_BASIC);
  elm_win_title_set(win, "Sample");
  elm_win_autodel_set(win, EINA_TRUE);
  evas_object_resize(win, 800, 600);
  evas_object_show(win);


  Evas_Object *box = elm_box_add(win);
  evas_object_resize(box, 800, 600);
  evas_object_show(box);

  Evas_Object *btn = elm_button_add(win);
  elm_object_text_set(btn, "Start Progress 0.0 to 1.0");
  evas_object_show(btn);
  elm_box_pack_end(box, btn);

  Evas_Object *wheel = elm_progressbar_add(win);
  elm_object_style_set(wheel, "wheel");
  elm_progressbar_pulse_set(wheel, EINA_TRUE);
  elm_progressbar_pulse(wheel, EINA_TRUE);
  evas_object_show(wheel);
  elm_box_pack_end(box, wheel);

  struct progresses p;
  p.moving = elm_progressbar_add(win);
  p.status = elm_progressbar_add(win);
  evas_object_show(p.moving);
  evas_object_show(p.status);
  evas_object_size_hint_align_set(p.moving, EVAS_HINT_FILL, 0.5);
  evas_object_size_hint_align_set(p.status, EVAS_HINT_FILL, 0.5);
  elm_box_pack_end(box, p.moving);
  elm_box_pack_end(box, p.status);

  evas_object_smart_callback_add(btn, "clicked", on_clicked_cb, &p);

  elm_run();
  elm_shutdown();

  return 0;
}
```